# On "graphs" of foliations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, foliations

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\mathcal{F}=\{\mathcal{F}_m\}_{m\in M}$ be a (regular) smooth foliation of $M$. The leaves $\mathcal{F}_m$ are smoothly immersed and moreover weakly embedded submanifolds. What can be said about

$$S:= \bigcup_{m\in M}\{m\}\times \mathcal{F}_m \subset M\times M$$

in general? Is $S$ also a leaf of some foliation of $M\times M$? If not, is $S$ still a weakly embedded submanifold of $M\times M$ or, if not, at least an immersed submanifold of $M\times M$?

**Edit 1:** $S\subset M\times M$ is an **immersed submanifold** if $S$ has a topology and smooth structure making the inclusion map $S\hookrightarrow M\times M$ an injective immersion. If $S$ is an immersed submanifold, $S$ is a **weakly embedded submanifold** if for every smooth manifold $Q$ and smooth map $F:Q\to M\times M$ satisfying $F(Q)\subset S$, $F$ is also smooth when viewed as a map $F:Q\to S$.

I do not know how standard this terminology is, but it is introduced on pp. 113-114 of Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", 2nd edition. Lee says that some other authors call weakly embedded submanifolds "initial submanifolds". See Theorem 5.33 on p. 115 of Lee's book for one fact about these, and Theorem 19.17 on p. 500 for a proof that every leaf of a smooth foliation is weakly embedded.

**Edit 2:** To be more explicit, I am looking for a definitive answer to the following multiple choice question.

Which of the following mutually exclusive statements is true?

**A.** In general, $S$ is a weakly embedded submanifold of $M\times M$.

**B.** In general, $S$ is an immersed but not weakly embedded submanifold of $M\times M$.

**C.** In general, $S$ does not admit the structure of an immersed submanifold of $M\times M$.

Comment: Each leaf of a foliation admits a manifold structure such that the inclusion into $M$ is a one-to-one immersion. What do you mean by "weakly embedded submanifold" or "weakly embedded initial submanifold"?

Comment: I think you should specify better what exactly you are esking for: you say that you would like "a proof, specific reference of a counterexample". Which is the exact statement you would like to be proved or disproved?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie thanks - I added Edit 1 with an explanation.

Comment: @user126154 thanks - I clarified in Edit 2.

Comment: Are you assuming a regular foliation? Are you ok with a "local result"?

Comment: @A.J.Pan-Collantes I am indeed assuming a regular foliation, but I would like to know a "global" answer to my question. (I already know how to produce at least one "local" result.)

Comment: That's the point, I think I can prove a local result for regular points...

Comment: "Regular" in what sense?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie by “regular” I mean that the leaves of the foliation have constant dimension, i.e. the foliation comes from an involutive tangent subbundle via the Frobenius theorem. That is the case I am interested in. I am guessing that what A.J. means by “regular point” is that leaves have constant dimension in a neighborhood of that point.

Comment: Yes, I mean foliations which are described, locally, by a constant rank involutive distribution. This excludes "singular foliations", which are described by submodules of $\mathfrak X(M)$ whose rank can "go down" in some points (the singular points).